# Help figuring out this Standard Normal Problem

Tags: distributions, self-study, mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution

[image: The Question]
Need to somehow prove P(Z less then z) is less then equation2

I dont know where to get started with this problem. Please help me figure out how to go about doing this problem. Thank you

So do i need to just integrate the equation given in part a from z to infinity ... how does that show its greater then P(Z less then z)?

Comment: So do i need to just integrate the equation given in part a from z to infinity ... how does that show its greater then P(Z<z)?

Comment: Use the self-study tag.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1415024/256501